# Rotation of colorbar tick labels in matplotlib resets tick label formatting

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I do rotation to the colorbar labels, the format I used seem to be reset (ignored).

The `fig.colorbar` does not accept rotation, while `cb.ax.set_xticklabels` does not accept format. 
I couldn't find any way to do both settings.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

test = np.random.rand(100, 100)
np.random.seed(12345)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(6, 5))
fmts = ["%d", "%.5f"]

for i, ax in enumerate(axs.tolist()):
    im = ax.imshow(test, origin="lower")
    cb = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, orientation='horizontal', 
                      format=FormatStrFormatter(fmts[i]))
    ax.set_title(f"Format {fmts[i]}")

    cb.ax.set_xticklabels(cb.get_ticks(), rotation=45)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The colorbar tick labels should be in the format of "%d" and "%.5f" but as you can see, neither does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the original formatting is kept when you call `cb.ax.set_xticklabels()`, you could add `cb.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter(fmts[i]))` to re-apply the custom formatting afterwards.

As an alternative, use `plt.setp(cb.ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=45)` instead to rotate the labels.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tested your second solution and it works as I expected, thanks! But for the first solution, the "rotation" is reset after using set_major_formatter, so it does not solve the problem... Anyway I will use your second solution as it works as I wanted! :)

Comment: @YoonsooP.Bach perhaps that's dependent on the `matplotlib` version, the `set_major_formatter()` solution keeps the rotation intact for me using python 3.7.3 and `print(matplotlib.__version__)` = 3.0.3  If you like, you can [mark my answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)